# Realistic smell effect

Tags: modeling, modifiers, effects

I'm about to model a piece of cheese, and I would like to give it some kind of smell effect as it's known from cartoons when a cheese is too old, or if someone with smelly feet takes off the shoes... Well, guess you know what I mean...

Now I want to make that kind of effect in blender. Of cause, it's going to be in 3D, and I hope it's possible to make it look a little more realistic than the cartoons. Also, I would like the "stink" to be half green, half transparent so that it is visible, and you know exactly what it is, but still not so green, that it looks more unrealistic than it's necessary.

I only need this effect for pictures, so it doesn't need to have an animation effect to it.

[image]

Comment: That can easily be done via smoke simulation or for better performance with textures and alpha channel.
cheers

Comment: Vote up for best title :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with (Since it wont be animated I decided not to use smoke sim).

[image]

1. I used grease pencil <kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse click</kbd> to draw the smoke.
2. Convert stroke to curves then in the curve menu I had the fill set to HALF and extruded until it looked good.
3. Then convert it to a mesh <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
4. I brought it into sculpt mode with a smooth brush and fixed all the wrinkles and odd looking things. Then used the blob brush to add thicker bulges where I thought they looked good.
5. Duplicated the smoke and changed how it looked with more sculpting and scaling.
6. The material added is just a simple diffuse (Principled BSDF) mixed with a transparent shader using a noise texture. I added a 2nd mix shader and transparent node to bring the overall transparency down.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not difficult to get an interesting result for this with a smoke simulation. Even though you don't need it to be animated, it will be far easier to achieve something sort of realistic.

You can download the .blend file at the bottom of my answer to use as a reference if needed.

[image]

---

1. Add normal smoke domain and flow objects.
2. Adjust smoke settings to get something that looks wispy/detailed enough for your taste.

[image]

[Full resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtONb.png)

[image]

[Full resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6trlm.png)

3. Add a volumetric material to the domain...mine looks something like below, but there is plenty of variations you could do depending on the effect you want.

[image]

> Note: These material and smoke settings are by no means refined. I played with it for less than 15 minutes.

[image]